# How to dynamically get path to HTML file in VSTO project for Outlook add-in

Tags: vb.net, vsto, outlook-addin

I am creating a simple Outlook 2016 add-in that will allow the users create a new mail message based on a HTML template.

I have created a `Ribbon` and added a button to it. Here is the click event handler code:

```
 Private Sub btnCreateMail_Click(sender As Object, e As RibbonControlEventArgs) Handles btnCreateMail.Click

    Dim app As Application = Globals.ThisAddIn.Application
    Dim currentAccount As Account = app.Session.Accounts.Item(1)

    Dim mailItem = DirectCast(app.CreateItem(OlItemType.olMailItem), MailItem)
    mailItem.SendUsingAccount = currentAccount
    mailItem.To = currentAccount.DisplayName
    mailItem.BCC = IdentifyContacts()
    mailItem.BodyFormat = OlBodyFormat.olFormatHTML
    mailItem.Importance = OlImportance.olImportanceLow
    mailItem.HTMLBody = GetEmailBody()
    mailItem.Subject = "Subject"
    mailItem.Display(False)

End Sub
```

`GetEmailBody()` function is responsible for reading the template and modify placeholders as required:

```
Private Function GetEmailBody() As String
    Dim strEmailBody As String
    Const strTemplatePath = "C:\Users\umute\template.htm"

    ' Read the template
    Using reader As New StreamReader(strTemplatePath)
        strEmailBody = reader.ReadToEnd
        strEmailBody = strEmailBody.Replace("{TodaysDate}", Date.Now.ToString("dddd dd MMM yyyy"))
        strEmailBody = strEmailBody.Replace("{Name}", GetCurrentUser())
        strEmailBody = strEmailBody.Replace("{Greeting}", DetermineGreeting())
        reader.Close()
    End Using

    Return strEmailBody
End Function
```

The above code works perfectly, however, I am not sure how to get the path to the template file dynamically, that is without entering the full path including `C:\Users\` etc. This is because I would like to ship the template file with the add-in to avoid relying on the user to keep it in their local hard drive.

I know that in ASP.NET it is possible to use `Server.Mappath("~/file.html")` to accomplish this but I don't know the equivalent of this when writing an add-in for Outlook.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After hours of trying, I figured out that the correct way to reference a file is to add it as a `resource`.

I added a new item of type `Resource` to the project and added the html template to it. Then, accessed the file like this:

```
     Dim strEmailBody As String = My.Resources.AllResources.Template
```